# parent resource as well as child resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am trying to figure out in which way I should configure my model/controller. The model is as follows:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"

  belongs_to :group <--- this is where I have the problem.

  has_many :people, :through => :exampleships
  has_many :exampleships, :foreign_key => "other_example_id"
```

I would like the Example to both have its own index/create as well as show up under the groups index/create as a nested resource. But for some reason I cannot get it to work.

my controller is as follows:

```
    class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :check_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /examples
  # GET /examples.json
  def index
    @examples = Example.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /examples/1
  # GET /examples/1.json
  def show
    @event = Example.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /examples/new
  def new
    @event = Example.new(params[:group_id => :group_id])
  end

  # GET /examples/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /examples
  # POST /examples.json
  def create
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @example = current_user.examples.new(example_params)
    @example.people << current_user
```

But then I get the error saying **Couldn't find Group without an ID**

here is an example of my group model:

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"

  has_many :members, :through => :memberships
  has_many :memberships, :foreign_key => "new_group_id"

  has_many :examples, :through => :members
```

Comment: can you also show the code of the form where the group_id is getting submitted?

Comment: it looks like the params[:group_id] is not getting going through... Assuming that went through, you can set @example.group_id=params[:group_id]